# How to use a NodeJS app as a Native Messaging Host for a Firefox AddOn on Windows?

Tags: node.js, firefox, firefox-addon, messaging

I've read almost everything I could find about the topic "Native Messaging" from a Firefox AddOn together with a NodeJS application on Windows.

Bottom line: I couldn't get it to work

I've setup the following (and also checked it again a minute ago)

- The Firefox AddOn has a custom extension ID and the necessary permission in its manifest

```
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "vlcconvert@theiner.org",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  }
```

- The manifest file for the Native Messaging Host I want to create with NodeJS has the following entries

```
{
  "name": "org.theiner.vlcconvert",
  "description": "Convert m3u8 into mp4",
  "path": "D:\\Project Folders\\NodeProjects\\NativeMessagingHost\\index.js",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_extensions": ["vlcconvert@theiner.org"]
}
```

- it is called `org.theiner.vlcconvert.json`
- I've made sure that `.js` files are associated with nodejs, so that starting (or doubleclicking) a `.js` file will start node together with this file
- I've set the default value of both desired registry keys

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\org.theiner.vlcconvert
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\org.theiner.vlcconvert
```

to point to the full path of the Native Messaging Hosts manifest file

```
D:\Project Folders\NodeProjects\NativeMessagingHost\org.theiner.vlcconvert.json
```

- The Firefox AddOn uses `let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("org.theiner.vlcconvert");` to connect to the host, which seems to be successful, because the port is open (and no error or disconnection appears)
- The Firefox AddOn later uses `port.postMessage('{"message": "This is a message"}');` to post a message to the host
- The NodeJS host uses `process.stdin.on("data", (chunk) => {...})` to receive messages on stdin and in the end create a file in its path which contains the message data
- I've installed the Firefox AddOn in `about:debugging`

But: The file is never created, even though I see no errors anywhere. Running the NodeJS app with `start index.js` works perfectly and writes the stdin input to the file

Did I miss something?

EDIT: I tried using CHROME.EXE from the native messaging host manifest, and it worked. But I want to use a NodeJS app, if possible.

EDIT2: When I use this `path` in the app's manifest as suggested by another blog article

```
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe D:\\Project Folders\\NodeProjects\\NativeMessagingHost\\index.js",
```

the port immediately disconnects with this error:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred
```

EDIT3: When I use yet another suggestion:

```
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
  "args": [" D:\\Project Folders\\NodeProjects\\NativeMessagingHost\\index.js"],
```

it fails with

```
Error: No such native application org.theiner.vlcconvert
```